# How to store multiple textfield values from multiple rows in different sections of UITable

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have two arrays of dictionaries to store data:

```
var workoutData = [String:[String:[String:Int]]]()
```

and

```
var workoutSets = [String:[String:Int]]()
```

I assign data to workoutSets when a checkBox is checked on the end of that row and then assign that `workoutSets` data to `workoutData` as a whole by:

```
workoutSets["Set \(indexPath.row)"] = ["Weight":Int(weightLifted)!, "Reps":Int(repsPerformed)!]

workoutData[exercise] = workoutSets
```

This works fine for the first section of data but when I enter data into the first row of the next section in the `UITable` and check the checkBox the values for the other rows of data are carried forward. I have added a screenshot so you can see what I am facing.

When printed, `workoutData` looks like

```
["Cable Row": ["Set 2": ["Weight": 10, "Reps": 12],"Set 3": ["Weight": 28, "Reps": 8],"Set 1": ["Weight": 45, "Reps": 5]], 
"Arnold Press": ["Set 2": ["Weight": 10, "Reps": 12], "Set 3": ["Weight": 28, "Reps": 8], "Set 1": ["Weight": 10, "Reps": 12]]]
```

[image: screenshot of problem]

Is there a better way of storing this data because I am also using the `workoutData` in the `cellForRowAt` method when loading the table so that the cells data does not get reused when a new cell is loaded.

Comment: Would probably need to see cellForRowAt method and full function that's called when checking the checkbox (if there's more).  You could also use structs to organize this information in a much clearer way than collections nested levels deep.  That's tough to keep track.  You could also use an 'index' property instead of 'set 1', 'set 2' etc.  Then you could just find the right set by index.

Comment: @Frankie If I wanted to use a struct, would you suggest something like:

    `struct workoutExercise:
    var name: String?
    var weightLifted: [Int]?
    var repsPerformed: [Int]?`

and update the data when each checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing such data which is a structured object with defined attributes and properties, it would make better sense to define it as an Object inherited from `NSObject`.

For this custom object you can define the required properties as "weight" & "reps". Also create a compound object of class `Set` to which you can add array of objects. Given below object hierarchy can be helpful.

`public class Workout {
    var displayName:String?
    var sets:[Set]?
    var key:String?
}`

`public class Set {
    var weight:Int?
    var reps:Int?
}`

`var workouts = [Workout]()`

`var workout1 = Workout()
    workout1.displayName = "Arnold Press"
    workout1.sets = [Set]()
    var set1 = Set()
    set1.reps = 10
    set1.weight = 80
    workout1.sets?.append(set1)`

`var set2 = Set()
    set2.reps = 12
    set2.weight = 80
    workout1.sets?.append(set2)`

`var workout2 = Workout()
    workout2.displayName = "Cable Row"
    workout2.sets = [Set]()
    var set11 = Set()
    set11.reps = 10
    set11.weight = 80
    workout1.sets?.append(set11)`

`var set22 = Set()
    set22.reps = 12
    set22.weight = 80
    workout2.sets?.append(set22)`

`workouts.append(workout1)
    workouts.append(workout2)`